# What is the difference between these two Electrochemical cell

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

can someone please tell me the difference between the 1st and 4th electrochemical cell in the picture, I understand that in the 4th cell Cu is 0.1M so does that make it nonspontaneous and would the cell voltage be different, and also someone know the cell voltage for the fourth cell.

[image]

Comment: Does the keyword "Nernst equation" ring a bell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ecell = Eocell - (RT/nF) ln Q**

Where Eocell is standard cell potential

Standard reduction potential of Cu2+ = + 0.339 V
Standard reduction potential of Zn2+ = - 0.762 V

We know that more positive standard electrode potential implies more tendency to get reduced. Hence Cu2+ will be reduced. That means Zn will get oxidised.

Standard oxidation potential of Zn will be +0.762V

Now net reaction:

Zn(s) + Cu2+(aq) --> Zn2+(aq) + Cu(s)

**Q = [Zn2+]/[Cu2+]**

***So difference in concentration in Cu2+ will make Q different*** and as Ecell = Eocell - (RT/nF) ln **Q** ,  ***Ecell will also change***

Now your second question is to find Ecell for the fourth cell:

Ecell = Eocell - (RT/nF) ln Q

Ecell = Eocell - (2.303 RT/nF) log Q

(i.e just converted ln to log base 10)

2.303 RT/F at 298K = 0.059

Ecell = Eocell - (0.059/n) log Q

Where **n** is the total number of electrons exchange in the reaction.

Q = [Zn2+]/[Cu2+] = 1/0.1 = 10

**Eocell = 0.339 V + 0.762 V = + 1.101 V**

(Eo cell i.e. standard cell potential  = standard reduction potential + standard oxidation potential)

Zn(s) + Cu2+(aq) + **2e-** --> Zn2+(aq) + Cu(s) + **2e-**

In the net reaction you can note that net electron exchange is 2. Hence n = 2.

Now substituting all the values in the Ecell expression.

Ecell = Eocell - (0.059/n) log Q

Ecell = 1.101 - (0.059/2) log (10)

Ecell = 1.101 - 0.059/2

**Ecell = 1.0715 V**